# Nexus 4 Lollipop install won't complete

Tags: nexus-4, ota-update, 5.0-lollipop

I updated my Nexus 4 to Android 5 Lollipop last night using the OTA update but the install process just won't complete. It has now been on the "installing system update..." screen for more than 7 hours! The status bar has been complete for at least 6 and a half of those hours too so I don't know what to do.

I've tried powering down and switching on again just now but phone goes straight into "installing system update..." mode.

Has anyone else seen this problem? Really worried me now as it renders my phone completely useless.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you feel confident to flash the stock nexus rom? It's a pretty simple process, it took me 5 minutes of fiddling and then 10 - 15 mins or so of installing on my Nexus 4. This would wipe your current data though.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me. I called virgin who told me to call LG. I have to send my phone for repair. Apparently this has happened to many nexus users.
They will uninstall the Android 5.0 update and send it back to you. But it might take a few weeks.